# Best way to run a system command in Chicken Scheme

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system, scheme, chicken-scheme

I want to run following Linux command which opens the document with application registered with the system:

```
xdg-open mydocument.pdf
```

I see that many commands for this are available: run, run*, capture, shell, execute, system* etc.

from: http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/shell and https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20utils

I also need the result of the command (ran successfully or not) from this.

Following (system without *), although not listed, also seem to work well:

```
(define result (system "xdg-open mydocument.pdf"))
```

Which of these will be the safest way to run system commands as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name of the document is hardcoded, it doesn't matter much what you use. If the file name is user-supplied, you must use `qs` to quote the arguments if you're relying on a string-based API like `system`'s.  It might be easier to pass arguments separately using [process](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20posix#process).

I don't know the shell egg very well, but if you want to get really fancy with shell calls, the [scsh-process egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/scsh-process) is a very nice alternative (full disclosure: I'm its author).